# Blog posts redirecting to random 404 pages

Tags: redirect

I cannot figure this one out, we have a site with 92 blog posts published. Of them, 3 do not work. When clicking on them in post list they go to 404, same when click view post or preview from the admin area. Hovering the link shows correct, but then they appear to redirect.

Nothing in htaccess that would cause this. We have 301 redirects set up for other pages/posts but not for the ones in question.

Anyone run across an issue like this?

Thank you.

Comment: hook `template_redirect` and `var_dump($wp_query)` to see what the query vars look like for those requests.

Comment: Thank you, could you direct me to an example on how to do that please?